# What do you call that little area just inside the front door of some houses?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

Some houses have a little rectangular area just inside the front door.  You then walk through that little area to get into the main areas of the house.  This little area is well defined with a wall on either side, with the front door behind you.

What is this little area called and is it considered a room at all?

Comment: I'd most likely call it an "entryway", though some would say "foyer".

Comment: _Atrium_ is another one.

Comment: Try *foyer* or *vestibule*.

Comment: Or _mud room_ or _vestibule_. But why are we all answering in the comments?

Comment: If it has a wall and another door, then it's a room (a mud room).  Otherwise you can call it the *entry* or if you want fancy, *foyer* (which has two possible pronunciations).  (US English)

Comment: https://www.hunker.com/13412225/the-difference-between-a-foyer-a-vestibule

Comment: @JohnLawler, when the word *atrium* is applied to a modern building, it usually refers to a fairly large space, not to 'a **little** rectangular area just inside the front door'.

Comment: Depends on whether you're writing an article for Architectural Digest or a letter to your sister.

Comment: In Midwest US, definitely a foyer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### vestibule

> a passage, hall, or antechamber between the outer door and the interior parts of a house or building.  ~ [dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/vestibule)

[image]

image source: [Wikipedia.com](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vestibule_(architecture))

Answer (score 5):

In the UK this would most commonly be called a *hall* assuming it has doors, arches or similar leading into other rooms. A hall is normally a long, often narrow, room with several rooms opening off it (*corridor* is rarely used inside the home) but the minimal hall is probably the one I had in my old house: about 1 metre square, with the front door living room door and stairs leading from it.

As to whether it's considered a room, that's variable. When thinking about decorating, for example, yes - "which room are you going to decorate next?", "The hall". But in terms of counting rooms to describe the size of the house, generally a hall isn't a room. Wider examples may be an exception to this - some are big enough to use a corner as an office or seating area.

Comment: Why has this been downvoted? I would have given a similar answer.

Comment: @KateBunting I was wondering that too

Comment: 'A hall is normally a long, often narrow, room' vs 'a **little** rectangular area **just** inside the front door' might be the explanation for the downvote. [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T6OzC8dacCM) has an article contrasting 'vestibule' and 'hall'.

Answer (score 1):

It's called a porch. After the porch is normally a hallway leading to the rest of the house and a stairway leading upstairs.

Comment: I've never heard someone use the term *porch* to describe an area inside their front door - it usually refers to an open-air, covered space outside the front (or back) door. A porch could be enclosed with windows or screens, but I wouldn't generally think of a porch as being "inside" the house at all.

Comment: @NuclearHoagie: I suspect this is a UK/US thing. In the UK it is common for a "porch" to be brick-built and entirely enclosed - so definitely "inside - though often protruding from the main part of the house. Doing Google Image searches for "usa porch" and "uk porch" suggests that this is indeed a regional thing.