# What do you call a connecting room that's too short to be a corridor, or even a hallway?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice

Imagine a room in the shape of a pentagon, a bit taller than this one:

## ⌂

The angled walls are scarcely wider than the bedroom doorways set into them. The other connected rooms have no common theme, a bathroom, a kitchen, and a dining room. There's a cupboard built into one of the walls and on the opposite wall, a mirror concealing an auxiliary electric panel. There is a light switch for the connected bathroom, and another switch for the ceiling light. Aside from these things and a rug, the room is featureless.

Surely this isn't a *hallway* or *corridor* - there's an implication of length. I've begrudgingly accepted *connecting room* as a placeholder, at least it's not *hub* or *junction room*.

Comment: It could be called a [**lobby**](https://www.lexico.com/definition/lobby). It has various locations, but is an area with rooms leading off it.

Comment: It could also be called a [**hall**](https://www.lexico.com/definition/hall), a term which has a wide usage from small to huge.

Comment: I've worked in a building where this kind of pass-through area was called a vestibule, but now I'm seeing definitions that call for it to be connected to the outside.  Does it have a door that goes outside?

Comment: Also anteroom and foyer.

Comment: You could call it a _connecting space_ (as it's not really a room) or a _circulation space_.

Comment: Do you have a photograph or two? Or even just a floor plan? Is this 'room' connecting more than two rooms? Is the primary purpose of this room as only a way to access the other rooms, or can one hang out in this room, going to this room for its own purpose and not just access to the others? Does it connect to the outside? Is it on the ground floor or above or below the ground floor?

Comment: @Mitch the diagonal sides connect two bedrooms, opposite of them is the bathroom, flanking the bathroom is the kitchen door (and hidden electrical panel) on one side, and the dinig room door (and built-in cupboard) on the other. Both switches are on the wall next to the bathroom door. We've had people "hang out" in this room while awkwardly trapped between the kitchen and dining room, never intentionally. The room has no purpose per se, nor furniture, nor a connection to the outside. It is on the second floor, but the house is a duplex so...

Comment: I would call the whole thing a doorway.

Comment: Either this or [What do you call that little area just inside the front door of some houses](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/501769/what-do-you-call-that-little-area-just-inside-the-front-door-of-some-houses/501772#501772) should probably be closed as a duplicate.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth, the room described is not adjacent to the front door or any other exit, I think the questions are distinct.

Comment: I'd say that the previous one is subsumed by this. Next, we could have 'What do you call a connecting room that's too short to be a corridor, or even a hallway, in a house not an office complex?'

Comment: It has a crystal chandelier in the center too. The ones I've seen all have a hanging light in the middle. I guess one could use some other form of lighting, like track, just nothing involving lamps or sconces around the perimeter as all the doors don't leave enough wall space for that in this room, which with all the doors open feels like a room full of rooms. The great room feels like a room full of rooms all coming in together. This room feels like a room full of rooms all wandering out and off. That's clearly the idea– the same but also opposite for these two central but separate hubs.

Comment: It's a design element that's very common in houses with great rooms, one that wouldn't not have a name because its purpose design-wise, meaning aside from function, is to create a yin to the great room's yang, a counterbalance to a space where all the rooms have no walls or doors separating them. Obviously, all houses that don't have great rooms have doors and walls separating its rooms, but this is laid out in a way so that it feels like a great room but uses so many doors in all directions it's making a meal of it, making a statement that's some kind of stylistic answer to the great room.

Comment: @BenjaminHarman -  you've offered a bunch of information describing the room, do you have any recollection of the _word_? Dialectal, long, short, etc.?

Comment: No. If I did, I'd have left it. One that I know it's not is "ben," because asking around, which is what I did before I came here, got me that answer a couple times, both of those friends independently of each other overlooking the fact that that's my first name, or else they tacitly thought it plausible that the name for it that I can't remember is also my own first name, like I can't remember my own name, lol.

Comment: @Heartspring Another I know it's not is "enfilade," not only because I do remember it but also because it doesn't fit, though it's close and it does make a logical (albeit not necessarily factual) case for the word I'm looking for existing, because if there's architectural jargon for a room and/or several rooms connecting with one another in a line with the doorways being the defining architectural design focus, how can there not be for a room and/or several rooms connecting with another concentrically in a cluster around it with the doorways being the defining architectural design focus?

Comment: @Heartspring You know, I just had a thought. Have you ever seen an upstairs of a house where all its doorways surround a railed central area, like a rectangular balcony looking down through the center on a large shared space on the floor below, though sometimes, a lot of times, it can instead look down on a stained-glass ceiling, the top side of a large stained-glass ceiling above a large shared space on the floor below, the lights in that upper floor area lighting that stained glass and so becoming downstairs light? The word could be the same as the word for that upper room-- maybe.

Comment: @Heartspring The house that's the setting of the Netflix show Locke & Key has such a room. So does the house that's the main setting of the new Sabrina the Teenage Witch spin-off on HBO. (Disclaimer: I have a 13-year-old daughter. Hmm, come to think of it, I guess that's not really much of a disclaimer, is it?)

Comment: *I JUST CAME ACROSS A POSSIBLE REASON FOR HAVING A HARD TIME FINDING A NAME FOR THIS ROOM-- IT'S NOT A ROOM. APPARENTLY, IN THE WORLD OF ARCHITECTURE AND HOME DESIGN, A "ROOM" IS DEFINED AS "AN ENCLOSED SPACE WITHIN A BUILDING **THAT IS NOT USED SOLELY AS CIRCULATION SPACE**, SO IN A MODERN HOME, THAT IS NOT A KIND OF "ROOM" BUT MERELY A KIND OF "SPACE." THE WORD IS A NAME FOR A KIND OF SPACE, NOT FOR A KIND OF "ROOM."* https://www.designingbuildings.co.uk/wiki/Types_of_room_in_buildings

Comment: @BenjaminHarman where is the house located, is it in California, maybe San Francisco? Was it built in the  1800s or more recently?

Comment: @BenjaminHarman I think transitional spaces typically have names - e.g. every suggestion on this page. Just no word for this kind of room - born of practicality rather than design or tradition.

Comment: @BenjaminHarman - I shudder to see that your bounty is about to end fruitlessly. (Though I may be speaking too soon) Best of luck in finding the word eventually.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To go through what it could be and eliminate what it can't be, there are a number of related words each with different nuances.

You are looking for a single word for a small room that connects to other rooms but has no purpose by itself.

- **vestibule**, **foyer**, **lobby**, **entrance** - These are all near the entrance (or exactly so in one case). A vestibule is a little room right behind the entrance door, possibly to keep cold air out of the rest of the place (like an airlock) or as a coatroom or mudroom. A lobby is a large waiting area, like at the entrance of a hotel. A foyer is an entrance hall, sort of like a very small lobby for a personal home.
- A **passage** or **gallery** is a long connecting space. It can be inside a building or the space between two buildings or a connecting corridor between two buildings but is covered.
- A **waiting room** is a smallish room that is intended for waiting. IT is superficially similar to the others because it connect other rooms with specific purposes. But it is not simply a connector because it has its own purpose as being a place to wait to get into other rooms.
- An **antechamber** sounds like it is part of a palace or pyramid, a waiting room before the main room
- A **hall** (for at least one of its primary meanings) is (generically) a connecting room that you walk through to get to other rooms. It has the connotation of being longer than it is wide.
- A **hallway** is identical logically to hallway and can replace 'hall' whenever that refers to the room. That is, if 'hall' is used for a building, you would not replace it with 'hallway')
- A **corridor** is a long hallway (which, etymologically, you can 'run' down). It is formally identical to a long hall, but I can only express vaguely that it gives the feeling of being the space of the hall in addition to the function of a hall.

So these are explanations of meaning but it doesn't really do any good unless you show how it might be used for your purposes.

What would you call that place? I'd call it a 'room' (because yes, it feels like 'hall' should be longer or at least less mundane).

For example, how would you tell someone to go replace a fuse in the electrical panel. Where is the panel?

> 'Go find it in the room between the kitchen and the bedrooms'.

I'd also say 'Go find it in the hallway...'.

But if you're *in* the bedroom and you want somebody to leave for a moment:

> 'Please wait for me out in the hall.'

You wouldn't say 'out in the room' because you're *in* a room already.

Comment: Accepted! Not for *room* but for being the first to offer *passage*. Comparing image search results between "hallway floor plan" and "passage floor plan" I see a lot of overlap, but with a measurable skew for long straight *hallway* rooms and small or angled *passage* rooms.

Comment: @VasiliySharapov 'passage' might be a word to use that is accurate in meaning and is not a rare word, but it is not the first word that a native speaker would use for your description because it, like gallery or corridor or hallway, has a connotation of linearity (long and thin).

Comment: With both hall(way) and passage(way), it could easily be clarified by prepending "short". It's really not a linguistic problem unless you're being particularly awkward.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds a bit antiquated, but 'antechamber' is a good fit (although could sound more than a bit pretentious).

As suggested by.Xanne 'anteroom' is a less formal synonym and might be more appropriate if you're not actually a mediaeval lord...

Comment: Ooh, it __does__ sounds pretentious, but between this and _vestibule_ I think it's less-wrong, making it my favorite so far. It does __feel__ a bit like a preamble to the kitchen.

Comment: No. 'Antechamber' is conventionally a room you have to pass through to get to a single major room – a 2-node rather than a 5-node.

Answer (score 2):

I like *lobby* and similarly suggest *vestibule*. Rather like other suggested words, it has a slightly more restricted meaning than you seek (in this case because of the “just inside a public” aspect of the definition, but is used more widely than the definition suggests.

> a small room just inside the outer door of a public building where you can leave your coat, etc
>
> [Cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/vestibule)

Comment: Used far more widely, including trains: the "V" in the unit designation "4VEP" stands for *vestibule,* and that's not somewhere anyone is supposed to leave a coat.

Comment: Lobby to me suggests a larger space, either the big space inside the doors of a hotel/public building, or a reception room.

Comment: You're right. "Vestibule" does tend to get used to mean more than that. It's become a sort of catch-all for about any room that introduces another room, even if Cambridge has failed to document that. I mean, it's heard often enough that way that I'd think it'd be common knowledge, so I can only imagine Cambridge is being a bit prescriptive and purist. I say that like it's a bad thing, which it is since English is established as a *descriptive language*, not a *prescriptive langage*, in its lexicon and grammar, but I hypocritically avoid using "vestibule" that way for the same reason, so. :/

Answer (score 2):

I am an American and I have no idea what we would call such a small room with doors opening off of it either. We actually have such a space in our house, but it is open to the hall, and because it has some shelving we usually refer to it (slightly inaccurately) as the hall closet. Having raised five children, I was often amused by the names they would invent when they did not know the common name for something. In that spirit I propose 'door-room'. Childish sounding indeed, but it describes the function exactly.

Comment: Hall-closet feels like a strong contender for what to call this room if you're trying to be brief and unambiguous at the same time, but only because we have no hallway - googling it brings up images of closets in hallways.

Answer (score 1):

Does this room also connect to the main entrance? If it does, the word **hall** would do. One of the definitions of "hall" is "a passage or lobby at the entrance of a house" (Chambers).

If the top of a flight of stairs leads to this room, it could be described as a **landing**.

Answer (score 1):

In architecture, the term for this type of space is *liminal space*. Some sources call it a *transitional space* or a *transition space*. This all-encompassing term can cover hallways, corridors, foyers of this type within a house.

[Wikipedia's *Liminality* article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liminality) has this brief explanation:

> In architecture, liminal spaces are defined as "the physical spaces between one destination and the next." Common examples of such spaces include hallways, airports, and streets.

I've found some more descriptive terms like a *transitional hall* or an *octagon foyer* (*octagonal foyer*) for the specific example of an octagon shaped transitional room/space in a house.

Examples:

> [image] 
> Octagon Flooring Pattern in Walnut 
> **Transitional Hall**, Minneapolis
>
> [houzz.com.au](https://www.houzz.com.au/photos/octagon-flooring-pattern-in-walnut-transitional-hall-minneapolis-phvw-vp%7E50260317)

> [image] 
> The **octagonal foyer** has original 1910 fixtures and a season mural by Rick Muto, a Rochester artist.
> [democratandchronicle.com](https://www.democratandchronicle.com/picture-gallery/news/2019/08/06/2-5-million-former-bausch-lomb-executive-brighton-home-sale/1930892001/)

> [image]
> "Nesting antique chairs and a stone Kouros sculpture embellish an **octagonal foyer**." - Eric Cohler Design 
> [pinterest.co.uk](https://www.pinterest.co.uk/pin/549931804477528626/)